# Not able to import Atari environments by Gymnasium

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to use ALE to test atari games with gymnasium. I am using the code below to create Breakout environment.

```py
import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5')
done = False
while not done:
    _, _, done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render()
env.close()
```

When I ran this code it returns the error below:

```
Error: We're Unable to find the game "Breakout". Note: Gymnasium no longer distributes ROMs. If you own a license to use the necessary ROMs for research purposes you can download them via `pip install gymnasium[accept-rom-license]`. Otherwise, you should try importing "Breakout" via the command `ale-import-roms`. If you believe this is a mistake perhaps your copy of "Breakout" is unsupported. To check if this is the case try providing the environment variable `PYTHONWARNINGS=default::ImportWarning:ale_py.roms`. For more information see: https://github.com/mgbellemare/Arcade-Learning-Environment#rom-management
```

My gymnasium version is: 0.29.1
My ALE version is: 0.8.1

I've followed the steps in the gymnasium [documentation](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/atari/)  but this problem occurs. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

From the gymnasium website's atari environment description [here](https://gymnasium.farama.org/environments/atari/), it stated that you need to run the command to install ROM licence first.

```
pip install gymnasium[accept-rom-licence]
```

Comment: I’ve already tried that several times with different versions and combinations but it didn’t work out.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new conda environment with Python 3.8 and 3.11 to reproduce your result. This works fine for me.

```
pip install gymnasium
 -> Successfully installed farama-notifications-0.0.4 gymnasium-0.29.1
pip install gymnasium[atari]
 -> Successfully installed ale-py-0.8.1 shimmy-0.2.1
pip install gymnasium[accept-rom-license]
 -> Successfully installed AutoROM.accept-rom-license-0.6.1 autorom-0.4.2
```

---

###### Your error message was reproduced ...

Your error message was reproduced when I tried to run your code *before* installing the last line: `pip install gymnasium[accept-rom-license]`.

###### Make sure that ...

Make sure that all of your command lines contain `gymnasium`, not `gym`.

---

Below is my test code for your issue, and this worked well. Hope for as you, too.

```
import gymnasium as gym; print(f'Gymnasium v{gym.__version__}')

env = gym.make('ALE/Breakout-v5', render_mode='rgb_array')
env.metadata['render_fps'] = 60
env.reset()
done = False
while not done:
    _, _, done, _, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render()
env.close()
```

Output

```
>> Gymnasium v0.29.1
```